# My dog poops in the house to let me know she's mad

Tags: dogs, behavior, toilet-training

No picture needed. :)
I have a 6-year old Weimaraner who gets anxious every time we leave the house. Crating her is not an option. We practice the normal routine of down playing leaving & arriving. She has started pooping on our rug despite us taking her out plenty. We've tried a lot of things but nothing is working. Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you taken her to a vet yet for a mecial check? Just to make sure this is not a medical isse!

Comment: Thanks for your response! We did & the vet's thought is that it may be related to a recent out of town trip. We had to leave her in a kennel & although they walked her 3x Day, it was not her routine.

Comment: I put a fence around where they pooped and put them in the fence.  I clean up the poop.